# Трёхуровневое меню в php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть [плагин](http://help-html-css.narod.ru/menu05.html) трех уровнего меню. Хочу внедрить его в php, не получается. Имею таблицу Catalog с полями id, parent, name. Смог только двухуровневое сделать, а прописать третий цикл не могу, рекурсией тоже тут не решить, т.к. в ней не прописать правильное расположение тэгов

```
$tree_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE parent= '0' AND checked='1' ORDER BY name");
while($menu_tree = mysql_fetch_assoc($tree_res))
{
?>
<li><a href="/catview.php?id=<?php echo $menu_tree['id'] ?>"><?php echo $menu_tree['name'] ?></a>
<?php
$sub_tree_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE parent= ' ".$menu_tree['id']." ' AND checked='1' ORDER BY name ");
        if (!empty($sub_tree_res))
        {
?>
<ul>                        
<?php
while($sub_menu_tree = mysql_fetch_assoc($sub_tree_res))
  {
?>
<li><a href="/catalogview.php?id=<?php echo $sub_menu_tree['id'] ?>"><?php echo $sub_menu_tree['name']; 
$res = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tovar WHERE Subdivision='$sub_menu_tree[id]' and checked='1'")); echo " <b>($res[0])</b>";  ?></a></li>
<?php
}
 ?></ul>
<?php
 }
}
 ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не вижу у вас рекурсии, а без нее вам тут не справиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня ваше меню получилось вот таким. Правда, дорабатывать надо. Мне проверить нечем

```
function menu($id)
{
    $tree_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE parent={$id} AND checked=1 ORDER BY name");
    while ($menu_tree = mysql_fetch_assoc($tree_res)) {
        echo "<li><a href='/catview.php?id={$menu_tree['id']}'>";
        echo "{$menu_tree['name']}</a><ul>";
        menu($menu_tree['id']);
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
    return;
}
echo "<ul>";
menu(0);
echo "</ul>";
```

Это получается вывод 2-го уровня. Третье - просто после каждого вывода, еще отсылка на функцию проверки товаров.

PS  А если у вас вообще разные запросы: и на первый уровень, и на второй, то каждый запрос сажайте в отдельную функцию.